# Scaling Multiple Identical MySQL Databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Our organisation unexpectedly increased its customer base, going from having one site utilising the system to 20+. Each customer relies on its own instance of our PHP application. When we've added new customers, we've simply just created a new EC2 instance and duplicated the database for each customer.

The two issues we found were that having one server per customer wasn't effective and we needed something more scalable so opted for a load-balanced solution. The second issue we're experiencing is that during periods of high traffic, our system is bottlenecked by the single RDS instance. Because we've just duplicated each customer's database, we're in a bit of a sticky position as we can't scale the database directly and setting up separate RDS instances looks pricey!

My devop skills aren't great, hence the question in here so could do with a bit of advice with what to do or whether I'm missing something!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to create a new database for each customer. I would create a single database which is easier to scale, and add in each table a customer_id column.

That single database could have each table partitioned by the customer_id column.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/27/what-is-mysql-partitioning/